# Should I worry about bit order?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have reached a point in the design of a library where I am horrified by endianness.
I can easily deal with the order of bytes, but the order of bits introduces a huge level of complexity in my code.

What I am doing is converting a `uint` to bytes, in network byte order (big endian).
However, I use the most significant crumb (2 bits, from first [most significant] byte) for something else, storing another number.

Normally, I use these lines for writing and reading the crumb:

```
bytes[0] |= 0xC0 // Writing 11 to the most significant crumb. It could be 10 or 01 too. Before the disjunction, I know those two bits are 0.  
(bytes[0] & 0xC0) >> 6 // Getting the most significant crumb and shifting it to the right, in the least significant place.
```

To me, all these seem to assume that the most significant bit comes first.
If it didn't, my pair of operations would basically turn 00000011 into 00001100, which is not a value I need.
This data is stored in a file and may be accessed elsewhere. If the storing machine and the reading machine use different bit orders, the reader will get garbage.

I also don't remember ever reading a piece of code which reacts to the order of bits.

So, my question is: Am I just being paranoid or my C# library could ever be used on an LSB-first machine? (under .NET or Mono; Windows, Unix, Android, iOS, whatever)
If so, how can I efficiently handle the possibilities and be able to retrieve my 2-bit number correctly?

Comment: Endian does not affect bit order, only byte order.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering As if everybody decided that the most significant bit comes first...

Comment: I **think** all .NET implementations are supposed to treat endian-ness the same (I think it was part of the spec), however, I might be wrong about this. However, the only place in a library I would consider accounting for things being wrong endian is at input-points to the library, ie. any method that's public and accept something that can be wrong.

Comment: There is no "first". The most significant bit is .. the most significant. It's neither first nor last. There is no measurement you can do on the system that could show a difference - operators on integers always work exactly the same way.

Comment: @harold yes there is: you simply read the raw bytes as bytes, for example by using `unsafe` code to treat an `int` variable as a `byte*`

Comment: @MarcGravell that's not an operator on an integer

Comment: @harold you said, and I quote: "There is no measurement you can do on the system that could show a difference". Yes. There is.

Comment: @Alxandr: How the endianness is treated is defined for each operation, but storing an `int` in memory uses the native endianness, and converting an `int` to a byte array using `BitConverter` uses little-endian.

Comment: @MarcGravell that doesn't measure anything about the order of bits within an `int`, only about byte order in which an int might be stored in memory, ie, not what OP is asking

Comment: @Guffa The `BitConverter` class uses the system's endianness. If you want guaranteed endianness, `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` guarantee little endian.

Comment: @harold I suspect we're arguing minutiae, but if I can set the MSB or LSB, and inspect the bytes to see where it got set: I can tell a lot

Comment: @MarcGravell you can tell something, but it tells you something else: it tells you which byte is first if you store the int in memory. You still wouldn't know which byte (or bit) is actually first in an int (which is a nonsensical concept anyway, because you can't inspect an int that way, you can only store it in memory or operate on it with operation that by definition can't show a difference)

Comment: @Vercas: You are right, the point I was trying to make is that reading a plain values like an `int` uses the native endianness, not a specific endianness.

Comment: I give up on trying to fully understand this concept, so I will quit asking further questions and accept Guffa's answer because it explains the effects it has on the operations I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the bit order. However the bits are handled in the CPU, the corresponding bit operations work the same to the outside.

When you shift right, that is always towards the least significant bits. If the least significant bit is actually to the left inside the CPU, the physical bits are shifted to the left, but the representation of the number outside the CPU is still with the least significant bit to the right, and the meaning of the operator is the same on any CPU.

When you make a bitwise or with `0xC0` it doesn't matter where the bits are, because the most significant bit in the value and the most significant bit in `0xC0` is in the same place.

Comment: Alright, but the real issue is misinterpretation of the bits when the same data is transferred from an LSB-0 to a MSB-0 machine.

Comment: @Vercas: However you transfer the data, the medium has a specific bit order, and the value gets translated at each step. In the end the byte value still has the same meaning.

Comment: The "translation" you speak of - I can't imagine where and how that would take place.

Comment: @Vercas: If you for example send the data over a network, then the bits are sent serially so there is no left or right, only first and last. On the other end it has to be translated back into a byte, so it has to know which bit goes where, i.e. which bit that is the most significant one.

Comment: I must be seriously braindead right now to miss the points that you and Marc are trying to make... Or you don't understand what my question really is. You just said "*it has to know which bit goes where, i.e. which bit that is the most significant one*". Well, how?

Comment: @Vercas: That's defined in the standards for whatever medium you are using to move the data. The network protocol defines where the most siginificant bit is.

Comment: Ah... Now that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using things like shift operations: you're fine. Endianness doesn't impact these: they will behave the same on any *-endian architecture - simply: how it works internally may change between CPUs, but you'll always get the same answers, as seen from regular code.

Endianness really only affects direct value-to-bytes interpretations, for example using `unsafe` code or `BitConverter` to get (or set) the raw bytes behind an `int` or a `double`, an explicit layout "union" struct that overlaps the bytes of different fields. If you aren't doing *that type of thing*, then you don't need to worry about CPU endianness.

Comment: If on computer A I write 11000000, which would mean to it 128 + 64 = 192, and computer B uses the opposite order, it will read number 3. How would I solve this?

Comment: @Vercas actually, in most endian discusses, the conflict there is over 192 vs -1073741824 (assuming that is an `int`); but you would only **ever** see that if you were reading raw butes: for example reading 4 bytes from a file or socket and coercing them via `unsafe` code directly to an `int`. And in that scenario, the fix is: make sure you account for endianness when reading raw data from a file or socket. In regular C#, including both arithmetic and bitwise operations: it will always act like 192

Comment: @Vercas emphasis: endianness is almost always primarily about byte order, not bit order

Comment: Would every implementation of `System.IO.Stream` know if the source comes in reversed order? The only way I can think of is storing a "magic" byte at the beginning of my data blob, which would have a known value. If that happens to be different than expected when reading, all bits would have to be flipped in every byte. Also, I said 3 because I was talking about bits inside bytes specifically. I already account for byte endianness in my code.

Comment: @Vercas no, streams don't have a concept of order **at all**: all they are is a sequence of bytes. So the important question is: what order are the bytes in? Bit order is not endinan-ness in the usual sense. You don't need to worry about that changing.